# Get nth day of each month between two dates

Tags: php

Now I am working in project there I need some dates for my calcluations. Actually I need nth day of each month between two dates.

For example if I need `12th` day of each month between `01-10-2014` and `14-02-2015`. Consider I have the following code:

```
//date format is d-m-Y
$start_date  = "01-10-2014";
$end_date    = "14-02-2015";
$needed_day  = 12;

$result  = array(); //array for getting result dates

//codes here

var_dump($result);
```

Then the result array must be like,

```
array (size=5)
      0 => string '12-10-2014' (length=10)
      1 => string '12-11-2014' (length=10)
      2 => string '12-12-2014' (length=10)
      3 => string '12-01-2015' (length=10)
      4 => string '12-02-2015' (length=10)
```

Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: The dupe tells you how to do 99% of this. Just format the date to always use the nth day of the month and you're all set

Comment: How do you want it to behave if `$needed_day = 31`?

Comment: The day range should be between 1 and 28

Comment: @JohnConde.. Thanks bro.. The dupe helped me ;) Thanks for you guidance.